# php : The term 'php' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: php, console, wamp

I can't get this PHP variables to work. Is it the sole reason for this error?
My php dir in wamp `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25`, I have copied this to environment variables but nothing happens (I even restarted computer - Windows 10). I tried it with and without ending slash, and I have also tried putting direct link to php.exe (`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe`). Any ideas? Thank you

[image]

Comment: To use a program as a command, you have to add its folder into the $PATH. At the end of $PATH global variable, add  `;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\`

Comment: Well that was exactly what i have done? System variables -> Path

Comment: Always a bad idea to add any PHP version in WAMPServer to the PATH. Remember switching between multiple PHP versions is easy in WAMPServer, but not if you add a specific version to the PATH

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I don't care about switching PHP versions as I use only one :) I want to set Laravel project from console

Comment: How are you trying to run php. use the command php.exe. You should switch to Linux. It has better support for Php.